# get the header value of a max value in a row in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

So, I have a data like this:

```
0.0   25.0   50.0 
12.3  3.45   9.34 
4.97  6.81   5.61  
9.14  4.62   10.3
```

I need to get the max value from row (which I can get using df.max()), however, the result that I need in the column is the header value.

Result would look like this:

```
0.0   25.0   50.0   res
12.3  3.45   9.34   0.0
4.97  6.81   5.61   25.0
9.14  4.62   10.3   50.0
```

How can I do this in Pandas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `idxmax`

```
df['New']=df.idxmax(axis=1)
df
Out[979]: 
     0.0  25.0   50.0   New
0  12.30  3.45   9.34   0.0
1   4.97  6.81   5.61  25.0
2   9.14  4.62  10.30  50.0
```

Answer (score 3):

One way using NumPy:

```
df['res'] = df.columns[df.values.argmax(1)]
```

Indexing a 1d array (in this instance, columns) is often efficient:

```
df = pd.concat([df]*10**4, ignore_index=True)

%timeit df.columns[df.values.argmax(1)]  # 914 µs per loop
%timeit df.idxmax(axis=1)                # 47.5 ms per loop
```